# Haproxy 1.5 performance issues

Tags: performance, haproxy

I need to improve the performance of an haproxy 1.5 running as a load balancer in an Ubuntu 14.04 instance. I have an analytics like code on many sites and for every pageview the client asks between 2-5 diferent scrips of ours. The other day we received more than 1k requests per second on the load balancer and it started to run really slow. It reached the active sessions limit 2000 at a rate for 1000 per second. On the configuration we use option http-keep-alive 100 to maintain the connection open for 100 ms until it is closed. How can we improve this? What is the best config for this use case? I may be loosing many details here please ask for them is there is info missing.

**EDIT**

Here are some details:

I'm running an AWS ubuntu 14.04 server in a c3.xlarge virtual machine. There we use haproxy 1.5 to load balance web traffic between several app instances. (Every app has its own haproxy to load balance between its own app instances - deployed one per core).
The server only has haproxy and no other software installed.

The bottleneck as per haproxy stat page is the front end load balancer as at that moment it had a session rate of 258 and current sessions of 2000 (being 2000 the max), and all the apps had a 96 sessions rate and 0/1 as the current sessions. I would post image but because of my reputation points I can't do that.

This was the configuration at that point in time:

```
global
        maxconn 18000
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

        # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
        # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
        #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
        mode    http
        retries 2
        option  redispatch
        timeout connect 5s
        timeout client  15s
        timeout server  15s
        timeout http-keep-alive 1

frontend public
        log 127.0.0.1   local0  notice
        option dontlognull
        option httplog
        bind *:80
        bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/server.pem
        default_backend rely_apps
frontend private
        bind 127.0.0.1:80
        stats enable
        stats auth  xxx:xxx
        stats admin if LOCALHOST
        stats uri /haproxy?stats
        stats show-legends
        stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics

backend rely_apps
        option forwardfor
        balance roundrobin
        option  httpchk
        server  app1    10.0.0.1:80 check
        server  app2    10.0.0.2:80 check
        server  app3    10.0.0.3:80 check
```

The connections were very high, it seems like it was closing them (or closing at a really low rate).
CPU and memory usage was really low.

Now we changed that config for the following one and it's working without problems:

```
global
        maxconn 64000
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

        tune.bufsize    16384
        tune.maxrewrite 1024
        nbproc  4

        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

        # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
        # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
        #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
        mode    http
        retries 2
        option  redispatch
        option forceclose
        option http-pretend-keepalive
        timeout connect 5s
        timeout client  15s
        timeout server  15s
        timeout http-keep-alive 1s

frontend public
        log 127.0.0.1   local0  notice
        option dontlognull
        option httplog
        maxconn 18000
        bind *:80
        bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/server.pem
        default_backend rely_apps
#frontend private
#       bind 127.0.0.1:80
        stats enable
        stats auth  xxx:xxx
        stats admin if LOCALHOST
        stats uri /haproxy?stats
        stats show-legends
        stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics

backend rely_apps
        option forwardfor
        balance leastconn
        option  httpchk
        server  app1    10.0.0.1:80 check maxconn 100
        server  app2    10.0.0.2:80 check maxconn 100
        server  app3    10.0.0.3:80 check maxconn 100
```

However all connections are being closed on the return (and we have the same rate of sessions and requests).
This is not good also because we have to open a new connection for every client request (and we have 3/4 requests per client).
How can we achieve a good keep-alive (like 100ms I think could work), without hitting the max connections limit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The number you give are very very low.

Please give more details about your architecture, type of server, third party software running on it (such as iptables), also share your configuration.

Baptiste